# Why can't I use SendGrid library in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, sendgrid

Hello today my boss ordered me to use a smtp service named SendGrid and i wanted to know if it is possible to use SendGrid on a VisualBasic project. From their documentation i only see they have libraries on C# and not in VB, so I thought it wasn't possible.

I have referenced the library and imported the namespace, and tried to create an instance of `SendGrid.SendGridMessage`

```
Imports SendGrid

Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ' Create the mail object first, then add the properties.
        Dim myMsg As SendGrid.SendGridMessage() = New SendGrid.SendGridMessage()
    End Sub
```

But the compiler gives me this message

> Type 'SendGrid.SendGridMessage' is not defined

My IDE showing reference and code

[image]

Comment: C# and VB.Net both consume .Net libraries.  The language makes no difference.

Comment: It does not matter what the library is written in as long as it supports NET.  None of those namespaces you use in your app (`System`, `System.IO`)  are written in VB

Comment: Well i added sendgrid by using NuGet packages to my VisualBasic project, and i do exactly like documentation recomends me to do:
(https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/csharp.html)

but when i put 
`Dim myMsg As SendGrid.SendGridMessage() = New SendGrid.SendGridMessage()` 
my code says there is error there

Comment: Perhaps you should ask *that* question with the complete details.

Comment: `but when i put Dim myMsg As SendGrid.SendGridMessage() = New SendGrid.SendGridMessage() my code says there is error there`, did you **import** the namespaces by chance. From the looks of it, you ***probably did not*** as you are typing the fully qualified name... Also if there is an error, what would this error say as you failed to mention this error you are receiving.

Comment: @Zaggler I did do imports `Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports SendGrid` but when i type SendGrid doenst appear anything below the text for autocompletion.
The errors are `Type 'SendGrid.SendGridMessage' is not defined` and when click on the lamp it says to generate new class...

Comment: Here is a print of what i am saying
https://i.gyazo.com/08d51c8ceee98eb91fa9f08b41e6b7c8.png

Comment: What happens when you change it to: `Dim myMsg As New SendGrid.SendGridMessage`?

Comment: @Zaggler Same thing happens...

Comment: @Zaggler if i try to use SendGrid object it doens't work, but if i try to use .NET’s Built-in SMTP Library I can send an email, the problem is if you go to the source of the mail that was sent you can see from what computer it was sent from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working by installing the package **SendGrid-Net40** (and its dependencies below automatically).

[image]

This code will now compile

```
Dim myMsg As New SendGrid.SendGridMessage()
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much, i couldn't know what was the cause.
And thanks for editing my post you are kind sir :)